# кто знает как работает history mapper в питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, history, mapper

кто нибудь знает как работает history mapper в питоне?
почему в таблицу истории пишутся НЕ все поля основной таблицы ?

```
class TableNameOrm(DbNameMetaBase, MixinLocked, MixinCreatedAt, Versioned):
    __tablename__ = 'table_name'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    title = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
    image_type_code = Column(String(100), nullable=True)
    
TableNameHistoryOrm = TableNameOrm.__history_mapper__.class_
```

при апдейте таблицы TableNameOrm, в таблицу истории TableNameHistoryOrm пишутся все поля кроме image_type_code, туда пишет null
что нужно сделать чтобы image_type_code тоже обновлялся в истории?

Answer (score 0):

короче в проекте были роуты на другой проект, в котором по эвентам обновлялась таблица истории